# Do I need to delete old certificate after renewal?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I recently imported a new certificate into IIS. So now I have 2 of them for the website. The old does not expire till next month but the new one says it is valid today. Do I need to delete the old one? Or will it hurt to keep them both in IIS? TIA

Comment: Keeping two certificates is not a right thing to do.... Use to new one and archive to the older one

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one certificate at a given time for any endpoint.

So you don't need to delete the old certificate, but you can do so safely. Doesn't hurt to keep it, too. I'd just remove it and be done with it.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to archive it someplace.  We're talking about a text file, and not a large one.  But getting it out of the server is probably a good idea.  Less to keep up with, and perhaps less for any new person who works with the server to try to figure out or make a mistake with.

Comment: What @Xalorous said about it being a good idea to remove it to avoid confusion is very important. I once took over a server that hosted thirty domains, each with its own SSL, and there were three years of old certificates for all of them! That's a huge mess.